# How to add two group content controls to the active document in word add in - This is not a valid selection

Tags: .net, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, openxml-sdk

I have a Microsoft Office Word 2013 Add In, where I select some text on the active document with the mouse.

Then, I have a button on the `Add In`, when I click on it, it should group everything in that selection within a GroupContentControl_1. And then, it should insert another GroupContentControl_2 before the GroupContentControl_1.

The cursor will appear inside the GroupContentControl_2 and user can start typing anything.

I have tried many things but getting errors:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //This line puts everything in current selection under a new group content control
    GroupContentControl gcc1 = doc.Controls.AddGroupContentControl("A");
    //Select the cursor position before the above group content control
    doc.Application.Selection.SetRange(gcc1.Range.Start - 1, gcc1.Range.Start - 1);
    //Insert new group content control-2 before the above one
    GroupContentControl gcc2 = doc.Controls.AddGroupContentControl("B");
}
```

At the third line of code, I am getting the following error:

`This is not a valid selection`.

Comment: Having same problem unable to find a solution yet. if you find one please let me know as well

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to the problem. You need to consider following points in order to make it work:

- Range should be selected i.e you should make the object of range and call Select(); method on it to make sure it is selected.
- Selected Range should be valid i.e it should not contain any table and range text should not be null.
  in your code you are making range with null text you should make range like:

  ```
  doc.Application.Selection.SetRange(gcc1.Range.Start - 2, gcc1.Range.Start - 1);
  ```

points to test:

- I haven't added a control containing another control it may raise the same exception you can test that if you need to do that.

Comment: I left this approach and did something entirely different as I was not getting any solution. I will try this later when I get time. Did +1 for your effort. Thanks!